# typename in abstract template class in c++

Tags: c++, interface, typename

I am trying to make an interface that encapsulates the MinPriorityQueue and the MaxPriorityQueue. Both has an iterator and const_iterator (that is why I need an own priority queue instead of in the standard library that doesn't allow iterative access).

```
template <typename T> class PriorityQueueInterface
{
public:
   typename ArrayList<T>::iterator iterator;
   typename ArrayList<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

   virtual void insert( T item ) = 0;
   virtual bool get( T key, T& value ) const = 0;
   virtual T front() const = 0;
   virtual T back() const = 0;
   virtual ~PriorityQueueInterface() {}
};
```

ArrayList is my own creation.
This gives an error:
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
I don't understand, because it works if I don't define those typenames. Typenames work if the class is not abstract, but I want the interface to contain those iterators.

**Edit**: Ok, I think I found the problem, it is unrelated to this code. I recreated the original post, I hope someone will still find it useful.

Comment: Should I create a new question after this fix? The original might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `typedef typename` instead of `typename`.

The way you wrote the code, you are telling the compiler that the PriorityQueueInterface has a member called iterator and a member called const_iterator.

By using `typedef typename` you will tell it it has a *type* called iterator and a *type* called `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

You need `typedef`, not `typename`, to make a type alias. And you also need `typename` since it's a dependent type:

```
typedef typename ArrayList<T>::iterator iterator;
^^^^^^^
```

Your code declares `iterator` and `const_iterator` to be data members, not types.

Comment: A note for the readers : In C++11, `using  iterator=typename ArrayList<T>::iterator;` is another way to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `typedef typename` construction:

```
template <typename T> class PriorityQueueInterface
{
public:
    typedef typename ArrayList<T>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename ArrayList<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    virtual void insert( T item ) = 0;
    virtual bool get( T key, T& value ) const = 0;
    virtual T front() const = 0;
    virtual T back() const = 0;
    virtual ~PriorityQueueInterface() {}
};
```

`typename` is a (required in this case) hint to the compiler: the next identifier is a type name.
`typedef` used for define new type.

Answer (score -1):

Change typename to typedef.

```
template <typename T> class PriorityQueueInterface
{
public:
   typedef ArrayList<T>::iterator iterator;
   typedef ArrayList<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

   virtual void insert( T item ) = 0;
   virtual bool get( T key, T& value ) const = 0;
   virtual T front() const = 0;
   virtual T back() const = 0;
   virtual ~PriorityQueueInterface() {}
};
```

Comment: No, you need both, even if a certain popular compiler does choose to accept this without `typename`.